# Illustrator's outer glow blur has wrong size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator, when I apply outer glow to an object, and set its blur to a given value, the outer glow's actual size appears to be at least twice as large.

For example, in the image below, a screenshot I took, the left object has an outer glow with a blur of 0,1 cm. The leftmost black line is 0,1 cm from the object, and the rightmost black line is about 0,26 cm from the object, and marks where the outer glow appears to end.

[image]

[image]

Is this how the effect is supposed to work? If it is, is there a way I can easily achieve the size I want? I imagine changing the blur of the outer glow such that the effect becomes the size I want would work.

Comment: I just tested this and I can confirm that this is the way Illustrator behaves. I've never actually *measured* the blur before. I've always seen it as an aesthetic effect and just finetuned it until I liked the appearance. I can't tell you why It's a pretty limited and simple effect. You can't set the contour or anything. My guess is that Adobe have chosen to let the *Blur* field indicate the *visual appearance* of the glow - not the distance it takes for the effect to wear off completely. If they did, I guess users would find it strange that the blur was so narrow.

Comment: @Wolff Well, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Yes this is how its supposed to work. The radius is the size of the kernel but since its a random walk process it will  bleed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizes of Gaussian blur and its applications like glows and shadows are much larger than the used radius of blur. Gaussian blur effect is calculated when the vector shape is rendered to a bitmap for displaying.

Every pixel in the blur is a weighted average of all other pixels in the rendered shape including the transparent environment. The weight of a pixel depends on the distance from the pixel which has the turn to be calculated.

The weight vs distance is taken from the same bell curve formula which is known as gaussian probability distribution. The radius of the blur is the same numeric parameter which in probablity theory is called "standard deviation". So, an image pixel which is far away from the shape, maybe much further than the blur radius, gets at least something from the blurred shape  - just like Gaussian probability allows results which differ from the average much more than the standard deviation. At distance = blur radius the averaging weight function is still about 61% of the maximum.

In practice Gaussian blur doesn't reach the full image area, if the image size is big. To keep the calculation job reasonable blur is calculated only to the distance where its effect is estimated to become invisible. But that distance is much larger than the math parameter called blur radius as you have seen.

I must admit that when the graphic software became available for everyman, I at first imagined that blur radius works like the length of a gradient, but very soon it became clear that it's calculated in totally different way. There are good math reasons behind the apparent complexity. Some of them are explained in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur